# ASP web api. IIS 7.5 ошибка 404 на PUT методе

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Собственно сабж
Локальный iis express на Win 10.
Хостинг iis 7.5 на WinServer 2008

Есть PUT метод.

```
        [SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Документ изменен успешно")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unhandled exception при сохранении документа.")]
        [HttpPut, Route("updatestatus")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateStatustDocument([FromBody]DocumentStatusBLL document)
        {
            int _count = await _service.UpdateStatusAsync(document);

            return Ok(_count);
        }
```

На локале все отрабатывает, после публикации на хостинг получаю 404:

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *The resource cannot be found.*

**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

 **Requested URL:** /Rejected-By-UrlScan

Другие методы (GET, POST) работают без нареканий

web.config проекта

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />    
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось изменением настроек `urlscan.ini`. Соответственно добавил в разрешенные и удалил из запрещенных